# I'm getting inverse of matrix even if determinant is zero

Tags: python, scipy

I'm getting inverse of matrix even if determinant is zero. I tried with the code below:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy import linalg
matrix=np.array([[5,10],[2,4]])
print(linalg.det(matrix))
linalg.inv(matrix)
```

Comment: `NameError: name 'matrix' is not defined on line 5`.

Comment: Even with replacing the 'matrix' in line 5 with 'matrix23' i'm getting a `singular matrix` error, are you sure you're not calling `linalg.pinv` somewhere else?

Comment: hi, no i didnot use linalg.pinv

Answer (score 3):

The problem here is a disconnect between how different routines calculate the matrix determinant. For example:

```
import numpy as np
matrix=np.array([[5.,10.],[2.,4.]])
print(np.linalg.det(matrix))
print(np.linalg.slogdet(matrix))

try:
    invmatrix=np.linalg.inv(matrix)

except np.linalg.LinAlgError:
    print("inversion failed")
```

produces no exception and prints this:

```
-1.1102230246251625e-15
(-1.0, -34.43421547668305)
```

i.e. not using a direct algebraic calculation of the determinant (which `scipy.linalg.det` does) yields a non-zero determinant, because of accumulated floating point rounding error. Thus the standard linear algebra routines treat the matrix as non-singular and produce an incorrect inverse from an extremely poor conditioned problem.

(Tested with numpy version 1.15.4 and scipy version 1.1.0)

Comment: This is quite worrying. Should we all have little to no faith in such functions anymore? How can it be that a library like NumPy isn't able to handle the simple calculation of the determinant of a 2x2 matrix? I mean, I know you said it's because it's a non-algebraic operation but after all the years, I never would have thought np.linalg.det would produce such a wrong result for such a small matrix. It doesn't take into account the potential errors and warn the user? We just get a nonsense result back?Please can you stop me from losing all faith in this library!

Comment: I guess it is only worrying if you do not understand anything  about how floating point works. It isn't the functions fault, or Numpy's fault it is nature of using inexact representation (i.e. floating point) and expecting exact results. No self respecting numerical analyst would get anywhere near inverting a matrix in general, and certainly not one which might be close to singular.